# Will Git suite my needs? If so then which version?

Tags: git, github, version-control

**EDIT**: Returning to the question many years later is quite embarrassing! To any one who stumbles across this and thinks what a fool, to give some context at the point of asking this question I still didn't really understand what GIT was, and the people who gave me the brief were under the false belief that it was all that was required for a full CI/CD pipeline,  (which of course its not)... so what isn't included in the wording if my question was my assumption that it was a full CI/CD pipeline... this plus my lack of knowledge left me incredibly confused.

To anyone seeking knowledge, there are some kind and patient responses below, but the summary is to do a but more research and play around with GIT. It does version control... some other things... but mostly version control. GitHub / desktop / stash / bash are just other tools for using git or storing repository's, but GIT is the core software.

I really wanted to delete this, but decided against it as some kind people tried to be helpful and it felt unfair to then delete there answers.

**Original Question below:**

First of all, apologies if this is not the right place to ask this lengthy question. I have done quite a bit of research so far, and am at the stage of being overwhelmed with info, and just getting more confused.

I work for a company in a department that has just been merged into with IT area. The significance of this, and the reason for this question, is that I have been advised that we need to start using Git for version control. Which is all fine, however we seem to have numerous types of Git available, and I am struggling to determine which will be best for our team’s needs. The main issue being that the system we do development is an enclosed ecosystem, with its own editor. So for Git to work, it means exporting the developments to text files, which we can do, but we don’t work from these text files.

We have access to:

Git Enterprise, Git Bash, Git stash (same as bitbucket?) and Git Desktop (I think)

What we do:

The company has an accounting/leger system, and provides administration services to clients. From this system we provide reports to clients containing various info. Our job is to develop these reports and update them as required.

How we do it:

We develop these reports on a proprietary (some might say archaic!) system, using the system provided, and enclosed, GUI. The code for these reports are backed up as a text file. It is these text files that we would be looking to version control.
At the moment we have various area’s that we work in. We have the “live” area, which is where the reports get copied to once development and testing is complete. Then we have numerous “project” area, which start of as copies of the live area, and is where we do the development and testing of the new/amended reports.
Once the development of a report is complete, we copy the new/amended report from the project area, to the live area.

Question:

1. I am really struggling to visualise how this will work using Git. The way I think we will use it is,

- Treat the project areas as branches
- do the dev in the project area under a new branch
- then when the dev is complete, merge with the main version in the project area
- then (not sure of this part) daily export the files in the project area,
- find any that have changed (i.e. been merged with the dev branch)
- then merge any changes into the live report backups
- import any changed backups into the live area

2. Which Git tools to use? We need to be able to automate this process to some degree, needs to be relatively simple to use and collaborate over various locations (which is why Git is being pushed I imagine)

From my initial investigation, I am unsure of the best way to get started. The only experience I have of version control software was SVN, which I used as briefly as part of a module when I was a student.

I am not expecting a step by step guide from here, just some suggestion/advice of which interface will possibly best suit our needs. Maybe even some pointers on where to find good resources on where to get started.

Many thanks in advance to anyone who takes time to offer advice. It’s much appreciated!

Comment: Hello, Stack Overflow is not a great venue for this type of open-ended question--please try git.reddit.com or the mailing list https://git-scm.com/community . That said, let me quickly offer my opinion. Start small and simple--start by just tracking the live versions of the reports. I.e., whenever you deploy a new or updated report into live, track the exported text file in the git repository. In other words, don't worry about tracking development and testing versions for now--just track changes to the live versions.

Comment: Oh, and as for getting started, the website is good https://git-scm.com/

Comment: I'll give those a try. Also really good advice, good way to dip our toes into Git and see if it works for us. Many thanks for having a look Yawar, really helpful.

Comment: Note that "Git" is the version control system and you should just use the latest version for whatever platform you're on. If you want to use some Git GUI, that'll work, too. There's no need to standardize on a single Git client. Where there is differentiation is in various Git collaboration services, like Github and Gitlab, and how to organize your project. But they'll all work with any reasonable Git client.

Comment: I didn’t realise that Schwern, good to know. No one that I work with has come forward with any knowledge of Git so far, though I dare say as we start to use it preferences will be developed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a somewhat open-ended question, but I'll give it a shot. I'll address the issue of Git tools first; in your list of 'tools', they are not all quite in the same category.

Git Enterprise: This is meant to be a git repository, and hosted CI/CD (Continuous Integration/Delivery) pipeline. This means that it would store your code, and give you the ability to run test-suites before merging branches, private repositories, deploy directly to AWS (Amazon Web Services), 24x7 support, and much more. Essentially an enterprise swiss-army knife for development. This is comparable to something like Gitlab, and Bitbucket.

Git Bash: Unless there's a product I'm not aware of, this simply refers to using the Git system through the bash terminal (common command-line interface for Linux).

Git Stash: Again, unless there's something I'm not aware of, this isn't a tool, but a command available when using Git. Lets say you make some changes on your branch, and want to commit one part, but keep the other part local and out of the commit. Git stash lets you put changes/files into a stack of temporary items which are not committed, and can be removed and put back at a later time.

Git Desktop: This would be the GUI desktop client that is an interface for a repository like Github or Github Enterprise, in the same way that 'git bash' is the command-line interface.

It strikes me as a bit odd that you'd backup text-copies of your code, but not the actual code files themselves; especially if you're using Git. Unless you're using some very obscure language where the code is stored as binaries instead of just straight text, any code-files should work just fine with Git. Additionally unless you're running your own private Git repo, backup is normally handled by whoever you choose to host (Github, Gitlab etc.). Even if you run your own Git repo/server and are worried about backups, you can set up a system to mirror the repo, or use a RAID 1 or similar configuration for your server hard-drives.

As for how to use Git, what you should read up on is 'branching strategies' (https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows).

If you don't need to bother with supporting multiple versions, feature flags, etc. then here is one (fairly simple) model:

- Each project has its own repo.
- Use `git up` to make sure you have the latest copy of master.
- Create a new local branch to add a feature or fix a bug by `git checkout -b NewBranchName`
- Make changes as necessary and test locally on your machine.
- Stage those changes with `git add *` to add all, or `git add ...` with multiple file-names specified. "Staged" changes are what will be officially added when you commit.
- Use `git status` to check which files have been added/modified/deleted.
- Use `git commit -m "Commit title" -m "Fixed bug xyz"` to commit your changes with a title and informative description of what you changed (you can see a history of commits per branch with `git log`). These changes are now officially in your branch, but only locally.
- Use some form of `git push ...` to push your changes to the remote repository.
- At this point if you use something like Github Enterprise, Gitlab, Bitbucket etc., you can have it configured to automatically run tests, and prevent merging to master if these tests fail.
- Assuming the above tests run successfully,  create a merge-request from your branch to master. Again, if you use one of Gitlab etc... there is a convenient web-interface for doing this. This will let you specify one or more approvers that must review the request before it gets merged.

Note that depending on the type of application you're developing and how testing is done, this may not be appropriate.

One last thought: from my (albeit short) experience, it's best not to have multiple long-lived branches for the same project. The longer they diverge due to new commits, the more difficult it is to merge them back together. If at all possible, make small commits, and test and merge your feature branches ever couple of days, or even daily if possible. This makes merges easier to review, merge conflicts (two people modified the same section of code) easier to resolve, and easier to isolate when a bug was introduced.

Hopefully that clarifies some of your questions. Best of luck!

Comment: Yes Asmodean, very open ended question, thanks for giving your take in it. Really appreciate the guidance and your time. You have probably spotted my nativity when it comes to Git pretty quickly! Also you are correct about the text file backups. In reality the actual backups are stored on a separate server that we don’t have access to, not sure what format. We refer to the text copies we export as backups, because we can import them back into the system if we need a quick backout.

Comment: Mainly we use the txt versions as a way searching through the thousands of reports for specific code or associations. At heart it’s a database with its own query language. The code/reports I refer to are basically database queries (not SQL but similar idea) and the output layout in a standalone file. Each report has its own text file. Again, many thanks and I will have a look at the guide you referred to.

Answer (score 0):

I've used *a lot* of version controls systems over the decades and Git wins hands down. But it's not without its problems. Here's a few general words of advice:

## Version control is an important tool, spend some time on it

A lot of people try to sweep version control under the carpet with overly simplistic workflows. They know how to commit, maybe diff, and that's about it. They might see version control as just a tedious backup tool.

Version control is so much more. It's intimately involved with how your code is tested, reviewed, debugged, and understood. It affects how you collaborate with others. It can rescue you from bad mistakes. With a good workflow, many people can be doing many things and not get in each other's way.

Git has a steep learning curve, its interface is awful, but it's well worth climbing. Git is very powerful, perhaps too powerful, and it's worth it to learn how to use it well.

## Don't try to turn Git into SVN (or anything else)

Git is extremely flexible, and you can make it work like version control systems you're used to. Don't.

Git is Git and has a very distinct way of doing things. One of the worst mistakes is not learning how Git works and instead trying to treat it as if it was something else, like SVN. `git add` does not work like `svn add` and `git commit` does not work like `svn commit`.

## Learn how Git *thinks*

Normally software has a good interface and you don't have to care about how it works under the hood. Unfortunately Git's interface is terrible and it lies to you about how it works. For example, `git log` will, by default, present a linear view of history; that is often a fabrication and a source of much confusion.

It will save a lot of frustration to learn how a Git repository is structured and what the commands really actually do, not what they say they do. This will allow you to solve problems by visualizing the current state of the repository and how to change it to what you want.

For all the complexity of the interface, Git is surprisingly simple under the hood. There's maybe four critical things to understand: the graph, the staging area, branch labels, and the role of commit ids. They're all easily visualized. I give a talk on it, [here's an old version to get you started](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ffBJ4sVUb4) as well as [a cheat sheet that might help make sense of the interface](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lssjbfkfvp7r4q0/Git%20Cheat%20Sheets.pdf?dl=0).

## Try Gitless

[Gitless](http://gitless.com/) is a Git client that improves Git's interface and reduces its complexity by focusing on the basic workflow and not the bazillions of special cases out there. It makes the learning curve less of a brick wall and more of a steep climb.

It's still Git, and the same repository can be used with Gitless or Git interchangeably, so there's no risk in giving it a shot.

Comment: Thanks Schwern. Really useful info. Will have a look at the talk and that cheat sheet is great, will definitely come in handy!